# How to get a bar that is fixed at bottom of viewport to become footer at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have searched exhaustively for a solution for this but have come up dry.

I am creating a page that will contain a lot of text to scroll through with an inline form that I want pinned at the bottom of the viewport at all times.

When the end of the page is reached, I want this bar to "become" the footer and rest underneath the last bit of content.

My problem: If I fix the position of this form - as shown here - it sits on top of (and hides) the last bit of my content at the bottom of the page. If I remove its fixed position attribute, it is not pinned at the bottom of the viewport while at the top of the list. I started playing around with some jquery solutions, but I have to imagine there is a simpler/CSS-based solution.

```css
#entrybar {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  bottom: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
}

.entryform {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" id="shoplist">

        <div id="top">
          <h1>Refer an expert: Your company's referrals</h1>
          <p><em>Please scan through the technology list below, and use the form at the bottom to suggest any experts in your network that might be a good fit.</em></p>
        </div>
        <hr>

        <div id="middle">


          <h2>Topic 1</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>Topic 2</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
            <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>Health</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>University and Building Technologies</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>Industrial Software</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
            <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>Health</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>University and Building Technologies</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>Industrial Software</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
            <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>University and Building Technologies</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>Industrial Software</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
            <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
            <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
            <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
          </ul>

          <h2>Health</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
            <li>Hey this is the last bullet here</li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      </div>


      <div id="entrybar" class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="entryform">
          <form class="form-inline">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="company">Company Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="CompanyX">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Contact</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Jane Doe">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="jane@company.com">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Refer</button>

          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move the entrybar at the same level with container fluid, and set a margin-bottom on container fluid.

```css
      #entrybar {
          background: #f1f1f1;
          bottom: 0;
          min-height: 100px;
          padding: 0;
          width: 100%;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 100;
        }

        .entryform {
          text-align: center;
          margin-top: 25px;
          margin-bottom: 25px;
        }

        .mar-bottom{
          margin-bottom: 125px;
          }
```

```html
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <body>
          <div class="container-fluid mar-bottom">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12" id="shoplist">

                <div id="top">
                  <h1>Refer an expert: Your company's referrals</h1>
                  <p><em>Please scan through the technology list below, and use the form at the bottom to suggest any experts in your network that might be a good fit.</em></p>
                </div>
                <hr>

                <div id="middle">


                  <h2>Topic 1</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>Topic 2</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                    <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>Health</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>University and Building Technologies</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>Industrial Software</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                    <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>Health</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>University and Building Technologies</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>Industrial Software</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                    <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>University and Building Technologies</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>Industrial Software</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>E-Commerce</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum fringilla leo odio, in porttitor neque tristique pulvinar</li>
                    <li>Integer ac purus consequat, bibendum tellus vitae, ullamcorper turpis. Etiam pellentesque, ligula vel semper fringilla, diam lacus mollis odio, a vulputate diam sem nec mauris</li>
                    <li>Curabitur sit amet dolor tortor. Cras gravida mi enim, ac pretium lacus pharetra non. Vestibulum non arcu enim</li>
                    <li>Ut commodo facilisis tellus, id egestas lorem pretium pellentesque.</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h2>Health</h2>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Nullam sed malesuada tortor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus</li>
                    <li>Hey this is the last bullet here</li>
                  </ul>

                </div>

              </div>


              

            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div id="entrybar" class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="entryform">
                  <form class="form-inline">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="company">Company Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="CompanyX">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="name">Contact</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Jane Doe">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="email">Email</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="jane@company.com">
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Refer</button>

                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>

        </body>
```

```
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically set the margin though? I want this to be responsive at different breakpoints. Using the solution above, if I create a large bottom margin to ensure all content shows on xs screens, it leaves a lot of white space on larger screens.